# Green Screen on Counter Strike on Linux Min

Tags: steam, linux, counter-strike

Good evening fellows, I've downloaded the Linux version of Steam and I've downloaded CS 1.6. After testing the game, I downloaded another game that didn't even load.

After this, I tried to play CS again but a green screen appeared on the menu screen of the game. I reinstalled the game but the problem persisted. I'm using an Inspiron laptop with Linux Mint Nadia installation.

The first time I tested the game was without a second monitor attached to the laptop; the first time that the green screen showed was with the monitor attached.

Comment: Detach the second monitor?

Comment: Already detached

Comment: I would suggest going to Valve for help on this. Their Linux stuff is all pretty new; I doubt there are many people who have encountered anything like this.

Answer (score 1):

Almost definitely driver issues. What driver do you have installed right now? You need to select a proprietary driver for best support/capability. What GPU do you have - ATI/Nvidia?

Depending on which GPU you have, you'll need to install a different driver so I can't help much more without more information.

In Steam, you can click the Steam menu (top left) and click `check for video driver updates` or something similar. This should let you know if you have a better driver available on your system.

Comment: thanks mate, I'll check and update my question. Just noticed that when you open it in windowed mode it works nicely...

Comment: Could be a difference in how the driver handles the two modes perhaps.